# Can someone get pregnant merely by using the swimming pool?

Tags: physiology, human-reproduction

This [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1198596/My-daughter-13-got-pregnant-using-hotel-swimming-pool-claims-mother.html) story says that a woman went to court as her daughter got pregnant by swimming.

> A mother is suing a hotel claiming her teenage daughter fell pregnant simply from using a hotel swimming pool.
>
> Magdalena Kwiatkowska says the 13-year-old conceived after coming into contact with 'stray sperm' in the water of an Egyptian resort.

Can this be true?

Comment: I don't know how to prove this as false (Due we don't know chlorine level). I guess it is possible, but the chance should be roughly equal to a comet strinking the earth.

Comment: The idea that you can get pregnant from swimming is an [old urban legend](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=1FVkhwB5cVAC&lpg=PR9&ots=ArdW6pnLVh&pg=PA30#v=onepage).

Comment: Also to isolate all possible causations to one swim in a pool sounds like the hopeful thinking of someone who wants to maintain their own or their child's innocence.

Answer (score 13):

According to [American Pregnancy](http://www.americanpregnancy.org/preventingpregnancy/pregnancyfaqmyths.html) it looks really improbable. Similar statements are made on the [Oakland University website](http://www2.oakland.edu/biology/lindemann/faq.htm)  and on [this website](http://contraception.about.com/od/contraceptionmyths/p/watersexmyths.htm) about contraception (which explicitly states it's impossible).
The girls should have been swimming naked and the "father" should have ejaculated just outside her vagina as sperm would be killed in a few second in the pool's water and it would not be able to "swim" in a pool.

It is more likely she actually had sex and tried to hide it from her (really gullible) parents.

Comment: While this does answer the question, the source cited is not very reputable as it seems to be a bare assertion by the website author.

Comment: @MarchHo I added some more references